# Exit pygame fullscreen display by Keyboard event while doing other stuff as well

Tags: python, pygame

I want to exit the fullscreen mode of my pygame display by pressing <kbd>f</kbd>. I understand that I can archive exit fullscreen by:

```
pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
```

And get the keyboard event by:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            logging.warning("event")
            if event.key == K_f:
                logging.info("TOGGLE: toggle fullscreen")
                return 1
```

My problem is that I need to leave the function where the display is initialized. I can not stay there until an event comes up. But I noticed that getting the keyboard event outside this function does not work (no display -> no keyboard). Since I can not have two displays, I can note "fake" one for the keyboard event. I also don't want to rebuild my display again if there are no relevant events (otherwise I could probably just call the initializing function from time to time and check my events in there).

Is it possibly to disallow pygame making use of the keyboard? So I can use Keyboardinterrupt to get out of the fullscreen? Am I missing something? Thank you for any help. I hope it is not to confusing.

Comment: Can you please explain what the phrase "I need to leave the function where the display is initialized" means?  Is the code initialising the display in the main loop or suchlike?  I'm trying to work out why leaving full-screen is interfering with the keyboard.

Comment: Hello, i did it today. I have no idea what went wrong yesterday. Leaving full-screen is no interfering with the keyboard, but closing the screen is. I thought even leaving the function which initialized the screen interferes, but this is not true. I can post the code, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen) for `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()` states:

> This function only works under the UNIX X11 video driver. For most situations it is better to call pygame.display.set_mode() with new display flags.

So it looks like you'll probably have to recreate your top level surface.

Here's a minimal example that implements this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

def init_screen(full=False):
    resolution = (1024, 768)
    if full:
        return pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    else:
        return pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)

full_screen = False
screen = init_screen(full_screen)
finished = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
while not finished:
    for event in pygame.event.get():            
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                finished = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                full_screen = not full_screen
                screen = init_screen(full_screen)
    if full_screen:
        screen.fill(pygame.color.Color("grey"))
    else:
        screen.fill(pygame.color.Color("aquamarine"))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

If you'd like any further clarifications, let us know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working with raspbian stretch, so the the toggle command works fine for me. I solved my problem now. I think I was just a little confused yesterday.

Comment: No worries, you might want to include your solution as an answer so future folks that arrive on this page aren't disappointed.